# Google Maps API - addListener ignoring click events on map

Tags: javascript, api, events, click, maps

I'm trying to get Google Maps API to register a maps click and for some reason I can't get it working!

```
    map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: { lat: 53.3674604, lng: -1.2427984 },
        zoom: 10,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: false,
    });

    map.addListener( 'click', () => { console.log( "Hello"); })
    google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'click', () => { console.log( "Hello"); });
```

I've tried adding the event both ways -- I know I should only need one of these.

The exact same code is fine when added to a Marker. The exact same code with event 'center_changed' works fine.

For some reason it's just ignoring the click event on the map?

Comment: Your `map.addListener` seems fine to me; it's similar to what I use. In any case, you should just declare one listener so as to not invite a glitch. In any case, do you have any elements getting in the way of your click, perhaps some transparent layer over the map? Try using inspector and click on the map; what element gets selected first?

Comment: Nope, no transparent layer. If I do the exact same to a marker on the map, it works. Clicks and drags on the map work fine so events should be registering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being dumb.

The map had shapes on it, I was using the shape area to test my clicks. Discovered by accident that the click handler worked fine on a blank area.

Added the click listener to the shapes and it works fine.